# AngularJS global $http timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We can manually set timeout to each `$http` via `$http.get('url', {timeout: 5000});` Is it possible to set a global `$http` timeout once and it will apply to the whole application?

Comment: if you wrap your http calls in a service which does that then yes. or user some sort of $http interceptor service, also could be done... if you need examples let me know

Comment: @Jony-Y Thanks a lot for your comment. It would be nice if you could show an example how your suggestion can be done.

Comment: pretty much like @NetSou showed in the answer... just add your $timeout there or what ever you want it to do

Answer (score 8):

You can use request http interceptor. Like this.

```
angular.module('myapp')
  .factory('timeoutHttpInterceptor', function () {
    return {
      'request': function(config) {
        config.timeout = 10000;
        return config;
      }
    };
 });
```

And then in .config inject $httpProvider and do this:

```
 $httpProvider.interceptors.push('timeoutHttpInterceptor');
```

OR You can do like this also:

```
// this custom config could actually be a part of a more general app-level config
  // so that you need to inject only one global config
  myApp.value('http_defaults', {
    timeout: 150
  });
```

Here you can see more simple way Inject above `http_defaults`in every controller were you are using `$http`. And set all default properties of http request.

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, http_defaults) {

  // in case you need to change the default values for this specific request
      // angular.extend(http_defaults, {timeout: 300});

      $http.get("/xyz", http_defaults)
        .success(success)
        .error(error);
    };
});
```

[You can refer this](https://gist.github.com/adnan-i/5014277)

I would suggest to use first option.

Comment: would you perhaps know what the default timeout is for $http service? Or is there no default timeout (wait for ever)?